# Python invalid syntax error with 'end' parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying out the hangman code from invent game with python book ,I am stuck on an invalid syntax error with 'end' .

```
Here is the traceback: 
Line 82: print ('Missed letters: ', end = ' ')
Syntax error: Invalid syntax
```

arrow pointing at = sign.
I searched and found that as I am working on python2.7 , I should use from **future** import print_function , which i did and error still exists.

My code:

```
import random 
from __future_ import print_function

HANGMANPICS = ['''

 +---+
 |   |
     |
     |
     |
     |
     |
====== ''' , '''

 +---+
 |   |
 0   |
     |
     |
     |
     |
====== ''' , '''

 +---+
 |   |
 0   |
 |   |
     |
     |
     |
====== ''' , '''

  +---+
  |   |
  0   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
      |
======= ''' , '''

  +----+
  |    |
  0    |
 /|\   |
       |
       |
       |
======== ''' , '''
 +----+
  |    |
  0    |
 /|\   |
 /     |
       |
       |
======== ''' , '''

 +------+
  |     |
  0     |
 /|\    |
 / \    |
        |
        |
========= ''']

words = """ cougar badger beaver cobra lion tiger skin ventriloquist magician monkey moose pigeon 
rabbit rhino trout wombat kangaroo python lizard raven skunk peacock hoki crab prawns cancer 
sloth snake spider parrot penguin ferret eagle cock hen peahen turkey turtle dinosaur metaphor 
iteration object apple """.split()

def getRandomWord(wordList):
#this function returns a random string from the words list
    wordIndex = random.randint(0,len(wordList)-1) #as we count from 0
    return wordList[wordIndex]

def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS , missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print (HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)])
    print() #give space after every string character

    print ('Missed letters: ', end = ' ')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print (letter, end = ' ')
    print()

    blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)
    #replace blanks with correct guesses
    for i in range (len(secretWord)): 
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]
    #show secret word with spaces between each letter
    for letter in blanks:
        print (letter , end=' ')
    print()


def getGuess(alreadyGuessed): #makes sure player enters a letter and nothing else
    while True:
        print ('Guess a letter.')
        guess = raw_input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print "please enter a single character."
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print "you have already guessed that letter. Choose another."
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
           print "please only enter a letter"
        else:
            return guess #returns user i/p
#function is true if player wants to play again , else false
def playAgain():
    print "do you wanna play again? (yes or no)"
    return raw_input.lower().startswith('y')


print "<<<<<<<<<<< H A N G M A N >>>>>>>>>>>>"
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False 

while True:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS , missedLetters , correctLetters , secretWord)
    #getting a letter from user
    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess 

    #check if the player has won
    foundAllLetters = True 
    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
            foundAllLetters = False
            break 

    if foundAllLetters:
        print "Yes! the secret word is "   + secretWord + "! You win!"
        gameisDone = True 
    else:
        missedLetters = missedLetters + guess 

#check if player has exhausted his guess limits and lost 

    if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
        displayBoard(HANGMANPICS , missedLetters , correctLetters , secretWord)
        print " you have run out of guesses! \n After " + str(len(missedLetters)) + "missed guesses and" + str(len(correctLetters)) 
        + "correct guesses  the word was  " + secretWord  
        gameisDone = True 

    if gameisDone:
        if playAgain():
            missedLetters = ''
            correctLetters = ''
            gameisDone = False   
            secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
        else:
            break
```

Suggestions? 
  Thanks!

Comment: unrelated to your question but your whole method of getting a random word is needlessly overcomplicated. You can use `random.choice(wordList)` to give you a random word

Comment: true. i will tinker and fix it.

Comment: @falsetru  Thanks for the suggestions guys. fixed it. but I am not satisfied with the program , What if I wish to see the hangman figure only if I guess incorrectly? The current one adds to the HANGMAN pic even if I guess correct. any ideas?

Comment: @Teejay, You need to escape backslash (`'\\'`) or use raw string literal (`r'\  '`). Otherwise the backslash will be used to escape whitespace after them.

Comment: @falsetru sorry , I didnt get you. Apply the '\\ ' where?

Comment: @Teejay, String literals in `HANGMANPICS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo:

```
from __future_ import print_function
              ^-- single underscore
```

`__future_` should be replaced with `__future__` (two trailing underscores)

---

And the import statement should be at the first line of the file (before any other `import`s)

```
from __future__ import print_function  # <-- this should be the first
import random
```

---

In addition to that, all usages of `print` statement should be replaced with `print` function:

Statements like:

```
print "please enter a single character."
```

should be replaced with:

```
print("please enter a single character.")
```

Comment: @Chantz It's not Python 3.x specific syntax. Using `from __future__ import print_function` you can use it in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

`print()` in this context is the [print function](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#print) in [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/contents.html).  As parentheses are optional for the [print](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) built-in statement, `print` statements can resemble `print()` function calls.  Your `print()` function call appeared to follow proper syntax, which told me it was likely a problem with the `import` (such problems could also indicate a version issue).

You attempted to import the function with:

```
from __future_ import print_function
```

But you are missing a '_'.  It should be

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

I reproduced this bug in the command line with your import and with other prints.

```
bash-4.1$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 25 2014, 14:04:36) 
[GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print (letter , end=' ')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print (letter , end=' ')
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print ('a', end=' ')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print ('a', end=' ')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print('a', end=' ')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('a', end=' ')
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('a', end=' ')
a >>>
```

Answer (score 1):

first, you seem to be importing from

```
__future_
```

you should import from

```
__future__
```

(note last underscore)

second, this replaces the normal print with an actual print function, so instead of

```
print "your text here"
```

it should be

```
print("your text here")
```

gameisDone is not always initialized.
add gameisDone=false after

```
if foundAllLetters:
    print "Yes! the secret word is "   + secretWord + "! You win!"
    gameisDone = True
else:
```

raw_input IS NOT A STRING. it's a function. call it to get a string instead of getting the function. Like here:

```
return raw_input.lower().startswith('y')
```

should be

```
return raw_input().lower().startswith('y')
```

also you need to import random.

I ran your code with fixes and it worked.

Comment: I have fixed that one. Thanks. Could you tell me what the others are? Been debugging some , could have missed out on something.

Comment: gameisDone must be set or you will get errors. do this in the else after "if foundAllLetters"    also your raw_input should be raw_input() not raw_input  I will edit answer